# Does the following equation hold? $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\mathrm{exp}(-2kc) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the following equation hold? $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\mathrm{exp}(-2kc) = 0,$ where $0 < p < 1$ and $c > 0$ is some constant.

Comment: What do you get if you apply the binomial theorem to $(p\mathrm{e}^{ - 2c}  + (1 - p))^n$?

Comment: oh, it converges to 0

Comment: Note that you started the sum at $k=1$ and not $k=0$.

Comment: @Gary it was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Is $c$ greater than zero?

Comment: @StinkingBishop fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This binomial sum is $$S_n=(1-p+pe^{-2c})^n=[1-p(1-e^{-2c})]^n$$as
$p(1-e^{-2c})<1$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} S_{n}=0$